# Is it correct to say "in their excursion.."?

Tags: word-usage

When describing an event that affects the participant in the middle of an excursion, would it be right to say "in their excursion" or "during their excursion"? Is there a better way to phrase this. (I have to use the word 'excursion'.)

Comment: I would choose 'on' instead of 'in': "They saw a giraffe on their excursion".  'During' works too.

Comment: "During their excursion, there was a brief thunderstorm."  Sounds OK to me.  "In their excursion" -- no.   "They went for a hike on their excursion" -- OK.

Comment: "During" would be most idiomatic in most contexts.

Comment: Is it a Ford Excursion?

Comment: Jesse M No it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...during their excursion" sounds better. You could change the first expression to "...in *the course of* their excursion" and it would have the same meaning, but be a little wordy.